# Problem with measure theory argument.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Could someone point out the flaw in this reasoning concerning the equality of outer and inner measure on sets with finite measure?

Let $\epsilon >0$, and let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $m^*(S) < \infty$. Then there exist $U\supset S$ open, and $F\subset S$ closed with $m(O) < m^*(S) + \epsilon/2$ and $m(F) +\epsilon/2 > m^*(S)$. Then $$ |m(O) - m(F)| < \epsilon$$ by the triangle inequality. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this implies $m^*(S) = m_*(S)$.

There is obviously a flaw here, since this only holds if $S$ is measurable, but I made no such assumption.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $m_{*}(S)$ in the second inequality, rather than $m^{*}(S)$?

Comment: How did you define inner and outer measures? Probably the part with the **closed** set $F \subset S$ only holds if $S$ is already known to be measurable. Note that you claim $m(F) + \varepsilon/2 > m^\ast(S)$ and not $m(F) + \varepsilon/2 > m_\ast(F)$.